# Strange deserializing problems with generic types using Scala and Jackson and java.lang.Integer or scala.Int

Tags: java, json, scala, generics, jackson

We all know that generic types are subject to type erasure under Java and Scala. But we ran into a strange problem in Scala using Jackson and the Scala Jackson Module.

I created a small test to show the problem.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule

object GenericTest {

  case class TestWithInt(id: Option[Int])
  case class TestWithInteger(id: Option[Integer])

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val mapper = new ObjectMapper()
    mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)

    // Test with scala's Int
    val test = mapper.readValue[TestWithInt]("""{ "id" : 5 }""", classOf[TestWithInt])
    print("Test 1: ")
    println(test.id.get +  1)

    val test2 = mapper.readValue[TestWithInt]("""{ "id" : "5" }""", classOf[TestWithInt])
    print("Test 2: ")
    try {
      println(test2.id.get + 1)
    } catch {
      case e: ClassCastException => println(e.getMessage)
    }

    // Test with java.lang.Integer
    val test3 = mapper.readValue[TestWithInteger]("""{ "id" : 5 }""", classOf[TestWithInteger])
    print("Test 3: ")
    println(test3.id.get +  1)

    val test4 = mapper.readValue[TestWithInteger]("""{ "id" : "5" }""", classOf[TestWithInteger])
    print("Test 4: ")
    println(test4.id.get + 1)
  }
}
```

The output of the above is:

```
Test 1: 6
Test 2: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
Test 3: 6
Test 4: 6
```

Where does this different kind of behaviour come from? Generic Type Erasure, Jackson, Jackson Scala Module?

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with Scala to say, but my guess is that Jackson has a built-in converter that knows how to handle the conversion for the Java type but not Scala's.

Comment: Hmm, maybe ...created an issue for that, cross referencing this question: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-scala/issues/104

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is becoming such a common question that I wrote a [FAQ](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-scala/wiki/FAQ) for it:

> [A]ll primitive type parameters are represented as `Object` to the JVM. ... The Scala module has informed Jackson that `Option` is effectively a container type, but it relies on Java reflection to determine the contained type, and comes up with `Object`.
>
> The current workaround for this use case is to add the `@JsonDeserialize` annotation to the member being targeted. Specifically, this annotation has a set of parameters that can be used for different situations:
>
> - `contentAs` for collections or map values (supported)
> - `keyAs` for Map keys (currently unsupported)
>
> Examples of how to use this annotation [can be found in the tests directory](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-scala/blob/master/src/test/scala/com/fasterxml/jackson/module/scala/deser/PrimitiveContainerTest.scala).

There's a lot more detail in the FAQ for the curious.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation and the FAQ item!

Comment: @Christopher Currie, is this still the best way of handling this?

Comment: @foobarbaz I can't say; I've not maintained the Jackson Scala Module or done any work in Scala for many years. My hope at the time was that Scala reflection would improve this, but I recommend asking on the [jackson-user](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/jackson-user) forum.

Comment: For those who find this: the tests directory link is now [here](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-scala/blob/master/src/test/scala/tools/jackson/module/scala/deser/PrimitiveContainerTest.scala).

Answer (score -1):

It seems to be because `java.lang.Integer` has a [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#Integer%28java.lang.String%29) which takes a String, which allows the deserializer to use that for `Integer` whereas that is not the case with `Int`

Comment: No, if you run the program in the debugger and set breakpoints in the java.lang.Integer constructors with int and String there is no hit of the String constructor, only on the int one!